# How to know WebView has been already load url in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, webview

How to know did `WebView` had already load url inside ?

My way (using `delegate`) :

```
var loadStates=false
func loadPage()
{
    if loadStates==false
    {
        let url = NSURL (string: "https://www.google.com/");
        let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
        webView.loadRequest(requestObj);

    }
}
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView)
{
    hideActivityIndicator(webView)
    loadStates=true
}
```

Have some better way to do this ? like `wevView.isEmpty()==true` syntax in Swift way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how does one check if UIWebView is empty or not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581909/how-does-one-check-if-uiwebview-is-empty-or-not)

Comment: Have Swift way to do this ?